# How to output a file according to 2 input files avoiding MemoryErrors python

Tags: python, memory, awk, out-of-memory

I have two big tab-separated files, which look like:

### 1st File: inputFile1.txt

```
#CHR    #POS    #ID    #REF    #ALT    #IND1    #IND2    #IND3    #IND4
chr1    1000    .      A       C       0/1:3:2  0/0:2:8  0/1:8:6  1/1:4:1
chr1    1050    .      G       A       0/0:2:8  0/1:1:2  1/1:4:1  0/1:8:6
[...]
```

### 2nd File: inputFile2.txt

```
#CHR    #POS    #REF    #ALT    #IND5    #IND6    #IND7    #IND8    #IND9
chr1    1000    A       T       0/1      0/0      0/1      1/1      0/1
chr1    2000    T       A       0/0      0/1      1/1      0/1      1/1
[...]
```

Both files contain the same chromosome (#CHR), but a lot more positions (#POS) and different individuals (#IND).

My purpose is to create a new file based on the above files. This output file would look like this:

### Desired OUTPUT File: outputFile.txt

```
#CHR    #POS    #REF    #ALT    #IND1    #IND2    #IND3    #IND4    #IND5    #IND6    #IND7    #IND8    #IND9
chr1    1000    A       C,T     0/1      0/0      0/1      1/1      0/2      0/0      0/2      2/2      0/2 
chr1    1050    G       A       0/0      0/1      1/1      0/1      0/0      0/0      0/0      0/0      0/0     
chr1    2000    T       A       0/0      0/0      0/0      0/0      0/0      0/1      1/1      0/1      1/1
[...]
```

Basically, this output file has the same format as inputFile2.txt, including all the individuals of both files (#IND). It also contains all positions of both files but the information of each #IND may vary according to several conditions:

1) If #POS is present in only one of the inputFiles, add 0/0 to the information of the missing #IND

2) If #POS is present in both inputFiles, modify the content of #IND according to several conditions that I will not explain here for the sake of simplicity.

I already coded a script using dictionaries, which worked for small-size files. But as I am dealing with big files, MemoryErrors arise

My next trial has been creating the following code structure, but it's failed.

```
import sys;

outputFile = open("outputFile.txt", 'w')

with open("inputFile1.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t"):
        if line[0].startswith('#'): ## header
            with open("inputFile2.txt", 'r') as f2:
                for line2 in csv.reader(f2, delimiter="\t"):    
                    if line2[0].startswith('#'):  ## header
                        outputFile.write("\t".join(line2))
                        for index in range(len(line)):
                            if index > 4:
                                outputFile.write("\t"+line[index])
                        outputFile.write("\n")
                    else:
                        continue
        else:  ## positions from inputFile1
```

In this "else", I would like to check if the specific #POS being read from inputFile1.txt is in the #POS column from the inputFile2.txt (but without creating any list or dictionary since it would arise MemoryErrors). I already tried to read the inputFile2.txt inside the else with a loop and check if the positions are the same or not, but I miss the cases where the positions from inputFile2.txt are not present in inputFile1.txt, so I cannot add those to the outputFile.txt.

Should I tackle this task with another strategy? Or maybe awk?

Comment: If you sort your files on `#POS` then you should be able to operate on these files without building up lists/etc. by simply recording the current `#POS` in each file and constructing each output line as soon as you see the next `#POS` value and then throwing all the previous data away.

Comment: That's what I did, but I can only throw the data from inputFile1.txt away since it is in the first loop. But since the inputFile2.txt is in the 2nd loop and inputFile1.txt does not contain all the positions of inputFile2.txt, I don't have the chance to add that missing line... sorry, hard to explain for me...

Comment: Right, you don't loop over the files one at a time. You loop over both of them at the same time. You read line one from both files, process the line(s) with the lower `#POS` value then replace whichever line you used and start again.

Comment: How can I know the positions from inputFile2.txt that are not present in inputFile1.txt in order to add them to outputFile as well?

Comment: You will see all the positions from both files in numerical sequence. If there's a value that isn't in either file that you need to insert anyway that's a different question (and just requires testing that you haven't skipped a space before you write new output lines).

Answer (score 0):

## My Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import collections

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = collections.defaultdict(dict)

    with open('inputFile1.txt') as f:
        reader1 = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
        for line in reader1:
            # The for loop will "normalize" the #INDx fields
            for i in range(1, 5):
                k = '#IND{}'.format(i)
                line[k] = line[k].split(':')[0]
            key = (line['#CHR'], line['#POS'])
            del line['#ID'] # Remove this column
            db[key] = line

    with open('inputFile2.txt') as infile:
        reader2 = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter='\t')
        for line2 in reader2:
            key = (line2['#CHR'], line2['#POS'])
            line1 = db.get(key)
            if line1 is not None:
                line2['#ALT'] = line1['#ALT'] + ',' + line2['#ALT']
            db[key].update(line2)

    with open('outputFile.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
        fieldnames = ['#CHR', '#POS', '#REF', '#ALT',
            '#IND1', '#IND2', '#IND3', '#IND4',
            '#IND5', '#IND6', '#IND7', '#IND8', '#IND9']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames, delimiter='\t', restval='0/0')
        writer.writeheader()
        for k in sorted(db):
            v = db[k]
            writer.writerow(v)
```

## Discussion

In my solution, I use `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` so I can deal with each column by name. Here are a few notes about my variables:

- `line`, `line1`, `line2`: each of these is a dictionary where the keys are the individual column names, such as `{'#CHR': 'chr1', '#POS':'1000', ... }`. You can refer to each column by name, for example: `line['#ALT']`
- `db` is a large dictionary where each key is a tuple (#CHR, #POS), each value is an individual line (which is another dictionary, as discussed above).

The algorithm is as followed:

1. Open file 1. In this step, we get rid of the text starting with colons for #IND1 ... #IND4 columns. We also remove the #ID column as the output does not require it.
2. Open file 2 and update the columns. Updating is easy, with the `update()` call. However, special care must be taken for the `#ALT` column.
3. Open output file for writing. In this step, we specify the orders of the columns via the use of `fieldnames`. The `restval` field told the csv module to use `0/0` to fill in any column that are blank. Then we loop through the `db`, sorted first by the chromosome, then by the position (that is why I created the key as a tuple: to make sorting easier). If you don't care about sorting, just remove the `sort(...)` function surrounding `db`. For each element in `db`, we write it out to the output file.

The only concern I have for my solution is memory usage. If you have very large input files, you might run into memory errors. Let me know how it goes.